# Bounded solution for an equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider $x''+a(t)x=0$ that $a(t)$ is continuous an differentiable , if $a(t)$ is monotonic such that $a(t)\to \infty$ then all solution is bounded!

Answer (score 4):

Hint: if $E(t) = x'(t)^2/a(t) + x(t)^2$, show that $E'(t) \le 0$.

Comment: who gave this proof?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3155149/bounded-solution-of-x-atx-0?noredirect=1#comment6497725_3155149

Comment: Maybe [Lyapunov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_function)?