# How to prove any solution of the equation $y''+f(x)y=0$ is bounded on$(0,+\infty)$? Here $f(x)$is increasing and positve on$[0,+\infty)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I don't know how to prove the problem even when $f(x)$ is continuous. Maybe the problem forgets to add the condition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bounded solution for an equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2005944/bounded-solution-for-an-equation), though I'm not sure what the minimal assumptions needed to solve this are.

Comment: Thanks a lot.With that hint I can prove it.But I'm still not sure whether the condition can be reduced to that $f(x)$ is not continuous.