# Bounded solution of $x''- a(t)x = 0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question below motivated me to consider a related problem.

[Bounded solution for an equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2005944/bounded-solution-for-an-equation)

It is proven that the equation $x''+a x = 0 $ has only bounded solutions. Now consider a similar equation $x''- a(t)x = 0$, where $a(t)$ is a monotonically increasing function of $t$, and $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} a = \infty $.

It is conjectured that there is always one solution which is bounded as $t\rightarrow \infty $.

Can anyone give a proof?

Comment: Man, now it is a negative sign before $a$.

Comment: $x(t) = 0$ solves the equation, do you mean a “non-trivial” bounded solution?

Comment: There are basis solutions that, by the WKB method, asymptotically behave like $a(t)^{-1/4}\exp(\pm\int_0^t\sqrt{a(s)}\,ds)$. With the negative sign, you get a bounded function.

Comment: But this is not a proof. This is intuition.